# $.ajax not working for GET

Tags: rest, jquery

I have REST service for both XML and JSON formats:

http://localhost:5050/rest/rest/report/check/{id}/{checksum}.xml
http://localhost:5050/rest/rest/report/check/{id}/{checksum}.json

Example: calling http://localhost:5050/rest/rest/report/check/420/339d9146ddd3d6646a1fe93ddf4d7ab8c4a51c61.xml will return result:

```
<report>
  <id>420</id>
  <checksum>339d9146ddd3d6646a1fe93ddf4d7ab8c4a51c61</checksum>
  <checksumValid>true</checksumValid>
  <reportName>sprawozdanie 1</reportName>
  <userName>John Smith</userName>
  <state>robocze</state>
</report>
```

Now I want to call that REST service from JQuery (either xml or json, i don't care).

What I do is:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"http://127.0.0.1:5050/rest/rest/report/check/" + obj.id + "/" + obj.checksum + ".xml",
    success:function (data, textStatus) {
        alert('success...');
    },
    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("thrown: '" + thrownError + "', status: '" 
        + xhr.status + "', status text: '"
         + xhr.statusText + "'");
    }
});
```

and I end up with error function being called, with result:

**thrown: '', status: '0', status text: 'error'**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is http://127.0.0.1:5050 a differen't location than the script requesting from it? If it is, read up on CORS. Differen't port protocol or sub-domain does qualify as a different location

Answer (score 2):

you need to use `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` due to same origin policy.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem was trivial and apparently I used to hak it some time ago and forgot about it (damn i need a wiki :) ).

Any way the problem is so called 'cross domain' which was prohibited by deafult in my spring-mvc rest project.

What I did was creating a new filter

```
public class OptionsHeadersFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "360");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

and add it in my web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>OptionsHeadersFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>poi.rest.OptionsHeadersFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>OptionsHeadersFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Depending on your use case, setting "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" to "*" can pose [security risks](http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy)

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with same origin policy. Here's a quick way to test if this is the case:

1. start chrome via command line, using
   "--user-data-dir=C:\deleteAfterwards --disable-web-security"
2. attempt the same query

If it works, then your issue is same origin policy. This policy is a pain for working in a development environment, because you have to host your web service on the same host (no aliases allowed) AND port as the site hosting the JavaScript.

You can get both a service and your website hosted via the same server using a Proxy. This article is a great reference for Apache (WAMP), if that's what you happen to be using:

- [Apache proxy setup in WAMP](http://java-wisdom.blogspot.com/2010/11/apache-proxy-configuration-and-load.html)